# The derivative of $e^x$

Tags: notation, derivatives

We all know that the derivative of $e^x$ equals $e^x$.

I found this notation on Wikipedia:

$$\dfrac{d}{dx} e^x = e^x$$

Why isn't this expression $$\dfrac{dy}{dx} e^x = e^x$$

Is it because $$\dfrac{d}{dx} e^x = \dfrac{d \space e^x}{dx}  $$

I'm asking this because I have only encountered $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ when differentiating (mainly because I always use the $f'(x)$ method.

Comment: $\frac{dy}{dx}e^x$ is the derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$ times $e^x$.

Comment: Here $y=e^x$, so it makes sense that
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}y=\frac{d}{dx}e^x.$$ In other words $\dfrac{d}{dx}$ is an operator that acts on function of $x$. For example on either $y$ or $e^x$ in this case.

Comment: @KimJung-un Just to clarify for easily confused readers: "(the derivative of $y$ with respect to x) times $e^x$" and not "the derivative of $y$ with respect to (x times $e^x)$" :)

Comment: Using Leibniz notation $\frac{dy}{dx}$ instead of prime notation $f^\prime(x)$ or $y^\prime$ has advantages. A few that come to mind quickly: when  expressing the Chain Rule, $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{du}\frac{du}{dx}$ versus $(f\circ g)^\prime(x)=f^\prime(g(x))g^\prime(x)$, the former seems cleaner to me; when working with differential equations, the excess parentheses in $f^\prime(x)$ get in the way, and without enough context, what does $y^\prime$ mean? Is it $\frac{dy}{dx}$, $\frac{dy}{dt}$, or something else?

Answer (score 4):

Here $y=e^x.$  That's why $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{d(e^x)}{dx}.$ However if write down $\dfrac{dy}{dx}e^x$ it simply means $e^x\times \dfrac{dy}{dx}.$

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to talk students out of writing $\dfrac{dy}{dx}f(x)$ when the mean $\dfrac{d}{dx} f(x)$ or $f'(x^3)$ when they mean $\dfrac{d}{dx} x^3$.

If $y=f(x)$ then $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ is the same as $\dfrac{df(x)}{dx}$, and this may also be written as $\dfrac{d}{dx}f(x)$.  But $\dfrac{dy}{dx} f(x)$ means something different: It means you're *multiplying* $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$, which is a function of $x$, by $f(x)$.

Comment: So my final statement (only the final one) was correct?

Comment: Yes. ${{{{{{}}}}}}$

Answer (score 0):

Some write $y=f(x)$. then $y$ is a function of $x$ and you can
talk about $\frac{d}{dx}y$ which also has the notation $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

$\frac{d}{dx}f$ is a notation for the derivative of $f$ with respect
to $x$, $f$ is a function of $x$.

So if $y=f(x)$ then $$\frac{d}{dx}f=\frac{d}{dx}y=\frac{dy}{dx}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's untangle the notations you're combining.

$\dfrac{d(e^x)}{dx} =\dfrac{d}{dx} e^x$ indicates that you're taking the derivative of $e^x$. Normally, nobody uses the first version when the thing differentiated is more complicated than a single letter.

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{d}{dx}y$ indicates you are taking the derivative of $y$, whatever that is.

Now if $y=e^x$, then $\dfrac{dy}{dx}= \dfrac{d}{dx} e^x $  means the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Leibniz composed different notations
some of them are

- $\Large \frac{dy}{dx}$-here we need to know $y=f(x)$,

whilst in the following notations we have this in the symbols

- $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$

$D_x[f(x)]$

notice that

$\large \frac{dy}{dx}e^x$
is a product of two quantities
the

$\frac{dy}{dx}=f'(x)$ and an arbitrary function $e^x$